# Angular: run code before exit

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is there any way to run code just before an Angular app exits? I know how to do this in a controller, using $scope.on('destroy'), but I need to delete something in a Factory when the app is exited. I read about doing this in the run() function, but I'm not sure how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You could add your own watcher on document exit do smth you want to and force exit your app.

Comment: [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Illia Olenchenko and fracz! For future reference, this is the working code I came up with:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', 'Backend', function ($rootScope, Backend) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
        Backend.destroy();
    };
}]);
```

Backend is a factory which handles the initialization and destruction of the backend of my app.